# Text through div's bottom border?

Tags: html, css

I've managed to make my "div" (it's really a form) so that there's text at the top going through the top border. However, I'm wondering if there's a way to make text that goes through the bottom border as well?

Here's what I have so far:

```css
fieldset {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
  border-color: rgba(70, 124, 63, .5);
  padding: -11px;
}

legend {
  font-family: "Garamond";
  font-size: 13px;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
  color: #285125;
}

.info {
  font-color: #86A798;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Garamond";
  font-size: 10px;
  font-style: italic;
}

.maintext {
  font-family: "Gill Sans";
  font-color: #656757;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>HMM</legend>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/65CeLdF.gif" align="right" style="padding: 8px;">
    <div class="maintext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ornare est sed libero pretium commodo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nam commodo mollis turpis, fringilla vulputate
      erat elementum at. Maecenas ligula arcu, dignissim quis euismod at, molestie a magna. Donec semper commodo mi, sit amet gravida augue venenatis nec. Suspendisse eu sodales orci. Fusce ultricies ante ac luctus cursus. Interdum et malesuada fames
      ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nullam nisl ligula, maximus vitae tincidunt et, interdum quis lectus. Donec rutrum ante ac dapibus pellentesque. Phasellus non congue ex. Integer luctus nunc.</div>
    <div class="info">### - @.user</div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Any advice? I want *.info* to be at the bottom border.
I'm a little new to this kind of thing, so sorry if the answer is obvious. I've looked around to no avail.

Comment: Do note that `font-color` isn't a property. Use just `color` instead

Comment: Set the CSS property "bottom" to a negative number for the bottom text. You may also need to set the "z-index" to bring the text to the front.

Answer (score 0):

```css
fieldset {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
  border-color: rgba(70, 124, 63, .5);
  padding: -11px;
}

legend {
  font-family: "Garamond";
  font-size: 13px;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
  color: #285125;
}

.info {
  font-color: #86A798;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Garamond";
  font-size: 10px;
  font-style: italic;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -18px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.maintext {
  font-family: "Gill Sans";
  font-color: #656757;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>HMM</legend>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/65CeLdF.gif" align="right" style="padding: 8px;">
    <div class="maintext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ornare est sed libero pretium commodo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nam commodo mollis turpis, fringilla vulputate
      erat elementum at. Maecenas ligula arcu, dignissim quis euismod at, molestie a magna. Donec semper commodo mi, sit amet gravida augue venenatis nec. Suspendisse eu sodales orci. Fusce ultricies ante ac luctus cursus. Interdum et malesuada fames
      ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nullam nisl ligula, maximus vitae tincidunt et, interdum quis lectus. Donec rutrum ante ac dapibus pellentesque. Phasellus non congue ex. Integer luctus nunc.</div>
    <div class="info">### - @.user</div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Notice what I added to the "info" class:

```
position: relative;
bottom: -18px;
z-index: 10;
```

Comment: This doesn't quite achieve what I was trying to do, but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** `font-color` should be `color`.

One option would be to use absolute positioning on the `.info` element set the background color and use relative positioning on `fieldset` to contain the absolute positioned `.info` element.

```css
fieldset {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
  border-color: rgba(70, 124, 63, .5);
  padding: -11px;
}

legend {
  font-family: "Garamond";
  font-size: 13px;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
  color: #285125;
}

.info {
  padding: 0 3px;
  background-color: white;
  color: #86A798;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Garamond";
  font-size: 10px;
  font-style: italic;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -6px;
  transform: translateX( -50% );
}

.maintext {
  font-family: "Gill Sans";
  color: #656757;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>HMM</legend>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/65CeLdF.gif" align="right" style="padding: 8px;">
    <div class="maintext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ornare est sed libero pretium commodo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nam commodo mollis turpis, fringilla vulputate
      erat elementum at. Maecenas ligula arcu, dignissim quis euismod at, molestie a magna. Donec semper commodo mi, sit amet gravida augue venenatis nec. Suspendisse eu sodales orci. Fusce ultricies ante ac luctus cursus. Interdum et malesuada fames
      ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nullam nisl ligula, maximus vitae tincidunt et, interdum quis lectus. Donec rutrum ante ac dapibus pellentesque. Phasellus non congue ex. Integer luctus nunc.</div>
    <div class="info">### - @.user</div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Another option would be to wrap the text in `.info` in a `span` so you can apply a background color to just the text and then use relative positioning to move the down over the bottom border. A downside to relative positioning is the element takes up space where it originated from even though it is visually elsewhere.

```css
fieldset {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
  border-color: rgba(70, 124, 63, .5);
  padding: -11px;
}

legend {
  font-family: "Garamond";
  font-size: 13px;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
  color: #285125;
}

.info {
  color: #86A798;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Garamond";
  font-size: 10px;
  font-style: italic;
  position: relative;
  top: 16px;
}

.info>span {
  padding: 0 3px;
  background-color: white;
}

.maintext {
  font-family: "Gill Sans";
  color: #656757;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>HMM</legend>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/65CeLdF.gif" align="right" style="padding: 8px;">
    <div class="maintext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ornare est sed libero pretium commodo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nam commodo mollis turpis, fringilla vulputate
      erat elementum at. Maecenas ligula arcu, dignissim quis euismod at, molestie a magna. Donec semper commodo mi, sit amet gravida augue venenatis nec. Suspendisse eu sodales orci. Fusce ultricies ante ac luctus cursus. Interdum et malesuada fames
      ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nullam nisl ligula, maximus vitae tincidunt et, interdum quis lectus. Donec rutrum ante ac dapibus pellentesque. Phasellus non congue ex. Integer luctus nunc.</div>
    <div class="info"><span>### - @.user</span></div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```